# Как заполнить базу данных миграциями?

Tags: yii2

Собственно вопрос вот в чем мне надо заполнить таблицу данными о пользователе, это возможно выполнить через выполнения миграции ?
В самом классе Migration я нашел публичный метод insert но не где не встречал в документации или литературе для чего иго используют и можно ли вообще заполнять таблицы

Comment: если у вас проект-однодневка, то конечно же всё можно `$this->insert('{{%table_name}}', ['field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2' ...]);`, а по уму мы например описываем дефолтные данные в зависимости от их размера и размера проекта в разных местах, выполняя заполнение БД при первой инсталляции консольной командой `yii app/install` к примеру

Comment: Это тестовое задание просто надо развернуть проект с заданным одним пользователем, созданием ему роли и присвоением это роли пользователю правда как хешировать проект вопорос.